# Win 7 Wireless Connected With Good Signal But No Internet Access

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, internet

In Windows 7 I was connected wirelessly for about a week when one day I came home and the wireless was connected with a strong signal but it said that I had "No Internet Access"

It's been 3 days since then now and I have yet to find a way to fix it.

My wireless drivers are right off the disk that came with the wireless card.

Can anyone help me?

My problem is similar to these:

http://forums.cnet.com/5208-7589_102-0.html?threadID=120346
http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7network/thread/90841fe7-c910-424b-82d7-48be7ef69f39

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you deactivated the dhcp function somehow.
Try this to reactivate it:

1. open the Control Panel
2. click at View network status and tasks
3. In the view your active networks-part click at your wireless network connection
4. (if you see "IPv4 Connectivity = Internet" then you should be connected - check your router) if not: click at properties
5. Click at Internet Protocoll Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) and then at Properties
6. There check if "Obtain an IP address automatically" and "Obtain DNS server address automatically" are selected - if not, select them.
7. Click OK, Close, Close and check if the internet-connection is back now.

If it still doesn't work, please press WindowsKey+R, enter cmd, press ok, enter ipconfig /all press enter and post the information for the wireless adapter here.

Comment: Alright, I looked at those settings and "Obtain an IP address automatically" and "Obtain DNS server address automatically" were already selected. I've never messed with those settings before. Like I said, my computer wasn't even touched between the time where it worked and when it broke. I ran `ipconfig /all` and the results are here: http://friendpaste.com/4RJeAnW8iV7pizx3hezzgQ

Comment: hm.. in the log you posted it shows just a Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 2 - where is number one...? This is really starnge because windows 7 names an adapter just with a 2 if there is another one! but also this second one is deactivated, that means that you didn't select a network to connect to (click at the network-symbol in the right part of the task-bar near the clock, select your network and click at Connect - what does it show?). Also you should check if you deactivated the wifi using the button somewhere outside at the notebook - most notebooks have a button for this.

Comment: *facepalm* Someone downstairs unplugged the wireless router and plugged the ethernet cable into another computer. The reason why it was named "Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 2" was because I reinstalled the driver and tried to make a new network connection. Thank you for all the help, though!

Comment: ok... but the ipconfig /all answer really doesn't fit to this, because there you see that nothing was connected and you said you had a good signal and it was connected. weird. But anyway: good that you solved the problem :D

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem but solved it.

My Windows 7 laptop could access to the internet through my D-link router in about several days, then it suddenly said that it had no internet access although it had the connection with the router and the signal strength was excellent. I tried all of the solutions above and from other sources but they all didn't help.

Then I got notice of the Wireless LAN adapter *Wireless Network Connection 2* which I have not seen before. My wireless LAN adapter is named *Wireless Network Connection* and it is functioning. Then I tried to disable the Wireless LAN adapter *Wireless Network Connection 2* and it just... worked!

I do not know if this is a long-term solution to this problem because the Wireless LAN adapter *Wireless Network Connection 2* is still there although disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Unplug your router for at least a minute. (This will hard reset the router.) Then try to reconnect. This usually works for me. What happens sometimes with wireless is your computer will lose connection and try to reconnect with to the router with the same IP address. It connects with a conflict and the router denies access.

Answer (score 0):

This simple way can solve 2 possible issues: your firewall is blocking the connection or a problem related to IP or DNS adress.

1. click on the wireless connection icon in left lower corner.
2. Select the connected wifi that has an issue.
3. click "status"
4. under the section "activity" click "properties"
5. you will see several check box. uncheck the one of your firewall if you believe it could be the problem (you can check it again after).
6. select the line TCP/ip (if you have 2 protocol version, do it twice) and click "properties"
7. "obtain X automatically" must be check for both IP and DNS adress (I had a DNS adress writen that causes my issue ― any idea where it came from?)
8. check if you can acess to your websites

Credit to:
http://ccm.net/forum/affich-487006-wireless-connected-but-no-internet-access

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and it was solved by forgetting the WiFi network and reconnect to it.