# Cannot connect to wifi, but can connect through wire

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking

Today in the afternoon I started experiencing a strange problem with wifi connection on my laptop (in the morning it was still working fine). The problem is that I am not able to connect to internet via wifi, but connecting directly via cable works fine.

==================================================================================

I have checked whether the problem appears also on my Ubuntu system that I have installed on the same laptop, which worked without problems, so I think that the wifi card in my computer is OK and that the settings on my router are fine too. Also, I get no problems when connecting from my Android phone or form any other laptop/device that I have at home, so I suspect that the problem is somewhere in my Windows configuration...

I have tried rebooting several times, then I tried reinstalling my wifi adapter driver (as suggested at [Can't connect to Internet through WiFi, but can with cable](https://superuser.com/questions/736235/cant-connect-to-internet-through-wifi-but-can-with-cable?rq=1) and I've got my new driver from https://www.atheros.cz/getfile.php) and I have also tried restoring Windows to some previous configuration (as suggested in one of the comments under that question), but none of this really helped me.

I have also reviewed Event Viewer on Windows where I found several errors (mostly from today, but also several moths old) of type `1001` and `1002` like this:

`Your computer was not assigned an address from the network (by the DHCP Server) for the Network Card with network address 0x5CAC4C7763F2.  The following error occurred: 0x79. Your computer will continue to try and obtain an address on its own from the network address (DHCP) server.`

`The IP address lease 10.0.0.51 for the Network Card with network address 0x5CAC4C7763F2 has been denied by the DHCP server 192.168.1.1 (The DHCP Server sent a DHCPNACK message).`

But I am not sure whether these relate to my wifi connection problems...

==================================================================================

One thing I noticed though is, that when I boot my computer after shutdown, the wifi won't obviously connect, but then when I turn the wireless adapter off (from Network and Sharing Center/Change adapter settings), then wait until my laptop connects to internet via cable and then turn the wireless adapter back on, I am able to get the connection.
However I consider this only as a temporary workaround, since I can't drag the UTP cable with
me everywhere I go ...

Does anybody have any suggestions on how to fix this problem ?

==================================================================================
My configuration:
Wifi Card: Atheros AR5B97 Wireless Network Adapter
OS: Windows 7 64-bit
laptop: Acer Aspire Timelinex 5820tg

Comment: You have a corrupted wireless profile for the network card or for your network specifically. To differentiate, are you able to see other wireless networks?

Comment: Yes, when I click on the wifi icon in the system tray (next to the clock), I can see several other wifi networks. I also tried to connect to some that were unsecured, but I got problems too...
Also one thing I forgot to mention is that after I turn on my wireless adapter, I can see my home network, but after some time or an attempt to connect to it, it disappears...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can see other networks, it's not the card itself or its driver, so the wireless profile itself is busted. Change the name of your wireless network and attach to the new name, or delete the old profile (which has a lower success rate than the renaming procedure due to quirks of Windows, happy, happy, joy, joy).

Comment: I am not sure, that I did what you meant, but I went to my router settings and changed the SSID of my network to something else, which did not work, so changed it back to what it was and now it works :D
Anyways thank you very much !

Comment: So finally, it turned out that this fix was only temporary for me and when I turned my computer on the next day, the problem was back.
What really seemed to help me (I am good for over a day now) was to manually reset the router (with that special reset button at the back of the router box) and setup a completely new wifi network.

Comment: Which router model and version? Routers can often be radically improved by replacing their software with Tomato, DD-WRT,  or other open source firmware,  as the level of testing for an $80 consumer device is very light.  Did consumer telephone support for two and a half yrs and so many problems were caused by router software...

Comment: On the box it says `technicolor TC7200.U`

Comment: Sadly, not compatible with OpenSource DD-WRT or Tomato . Little information available beyond what I could see at https://www.google.com/search?q=technicolor+TC7200

Comment: hm, never mind, the most important is that it works now :D and thanks again for your willingness to help me