# Win7 cannot access wifi but wireless Ubuntu and cable are okay

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, router, dell-inspiron

My wireless does not work, but the ubuntu installed on the Win7 still works for wireless.

On my Win7, the triangle wifi signal is on. The network status shows it connects to Internet. But when loading a browser, it shows:
[image]

In addition, cable works.

I have install the "Intel 3160 7260 3165 7265 Wi-Fi Driver" from [here](http://www.dell.com/support/home/uk/en/ukdhs1/product-support/servicetag/djg0802/drivers) but not work.

My laptop is Dell Inspiron 5547 with Win7 installed. I am open to any suggestions.

[Here](https://superuser.com/questions/815785/cannot-connect-to-wifi-but-can-connect-through-wire) recommends to "Change the name of your wireless network". Can I ask how to do this?

Comment: The problem seems to be an incorrect DNS. Check configs in Ubuntu and replicate them in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Yes, it is the DNS problem.

[image]